# How can I increase the height of a span to a different row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

I know the title doesn't make sense but I don't know how to put it.

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/nr33k/embedded/result/

I want to increase the height of the well on the right to match the height of the two wells on the left together, so it looks like I have three small wells in one large rectangle. If I try to increase the height the obvious way by adding `height:150px` it causes the bottom well on the left to fall down. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the first two ''wells'' are in a row, while the third is in another row.

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">
    <div class="well well-small" style="height:50px">
      <p>hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class="well well-small" style="height:100px">
      <p>hello again</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="span8">
    <div class="well well-small" style="height:190px;">
      <p>hello one more time</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to `float:left;` your `row` class and then set the height of the span on the right.

`.row {float:left;}`

Here's a working sample http://jsfiddle.net/BUgQc/

Answer (score 0):

Make the left side two DIV's in one single DIV and float it left and make the Right side bigger Well div in a single DIV and float if left.... hope this will help for you....

Answer (score 0):

Check this example. Hope it helps

**HTML**

```
<div id="container2">        
    <div id="container1">
        <div id="col1" style="height:250px">
            <!-- Column one start -->
            <h2>Equal height columns</h2>           
            <!-- Column one end -->
        </div>

        <div id="col2">
            <!-- Column two start -->            
            <h3>Mac</h3>           
            <!-- Column two end -->
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#container2 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
    position:relative;
    right:30%;
}
#container1 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    right:40%;
}
#col1 {
    float:left;
    width:26%;
    position:relative;
    left:72%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#col2 {
    float:left;
    width:36%;
    position:relative;
    left:76%;
    overflow:hidden;
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eVt2C/)**

[Source link](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)